# Remove certain string from word Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a certain word within a word in a cell in excel that I'm trying to remove. For instance in one of the cells I have `P/N279-82345` and I'm trying to get rid of the `P/N` in the front but keep the rest. I know there is the like function but is there a way to use the like function to remove just the `P/N`?

Thank You

Answer is

```
x = Replace(ws2.Cells(i, 1), "P/N", "")
```

Comment: `Replace` is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `replace` function.

Syntax can be found here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPLACE-REPLACEB-functions-8d799074-2425-4a8a-84bc-82472868878a

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a VBA macro function you can use something like: 
Cells(1, 1).Value = Replace(Cells(1, 1).Value, "P/N", "")
where the Cells value is the range you want to search.

If you are looking for an excel worksheet function, you can use substitute:
=substitute(A1,"P/N","")
where A1 is the cell that contains the value you want to substitute.